# How can I get the own scope in defined module in require.js? The scope is 'this' and I want it to be the module itself

Tags: javascript, scope, requirejs

For example, let's say I have this module:

```js
define(['jquery', 'underscore', externalHandlers], function someModule($, _, externalHandlers) {
  
  var key1=1, key2=2;
  
  function get(key){
    //get a private key
  }

  function set(kv){
    //set a private key
  }
  
  function toBeCalledFromAnywhere(key){
    //this function can be called from anywhere
    this.get(key); //this here, should always be the module itself
  }


  function appendHandlers(){
    //this === window here, how can I bind it to the module?
    externalHandlers.appendHandler('toBeCalledFromAnywhere', toBeCalledFromAnywhere.bind(this)); 
  }
  appendHandlers();


  return {
    get : get,
    set : set,
    toBeCalledFromAnywhere : toBeCalledFromAnywhere
  };
});
```

As you can see I have an external module (externalHandlers) which handlers can be appended to and execute from another scope. I want to bind the scope of the module to this handler.

Is this can be achieved? Do I have a design issue or it's a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing which would be your "module object" in your code would be what you pass to `return` at the end of the RequireJS module. To be able to set `this` to the value of that object, you need to make it available to the scope of your module's factory function. So:

```
define(['./externalHandlers'], function someModule(externalHandlers) {

  // [... the start does not change ...]

  var exports = {
    get : get,
    set : set,
    toBeCalledFromAnywhere : toBeCalledFromAnywhere
  };

  function appendHandlers(){
    externalHandlers.appendHandler('toBeCalledFromAnywhere', toBeCalledFromAnywhere.bind(exports));
  }
  appendHandlers();

  return exports;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot this option for some reason :)

Answer (score -1):

define e.g. `var self = this` in your module and use `self` in `appendHandlers()`

Comment: Not good, "in your module" scope is the 'window' scope.
I'm trying an approach of wrapping the inner function in an object and returning that.